# Como testar a camada de serviços

Tags: java, hibernate, testes, jpa-2.0, testes-funcionais

Eu estou desenvolvendo um projeto web multi-camadas e multi-módulos. Para a camada de persistência estou usando JPA 2.1 e hibernate 4.2 e para os testes JUnit 4.
Nesta arquitetura meu projeto foi dividido em classes:

- GenericDAO (interface);
- GenericDAOImpl (implementação);
- EntityDAOImpl (herda de GenericDAOImpl);
- GenericService (interface);
- GenericServiceImpl (implementação);
- EntityServiceImpl (herda de GenericServiceImpl);
- Entity (POJO).

Naturalmente estas entidades possuem dependências entre si e mapementos one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one e many-to-many.
Eu gostaria de testar se tais entidades estão sendo persistidas, com seus respectivos relacionamentos, corretamente no banco de dados.

Iniciei o desenvolvimento destes testes utilizando um banco de dados em memória (HSQLDB) provido pelo spring. 
Criei uma classe genérica de teste GenericServiceTest que testam os métodos das minhas classes GenericServicesImpl e extendi para cada entidade específica, por exemplo EntityServiceTest. Uma entity pode ser qualquer objeto, usuário, conta, cidade, país ...

Então ao executar a classe de teste EntityServiceTest todos os métodos e anotações do JUnit localizadas na classe GenericServiceTest são herdados e o teste para esta entidade específica é realizado.

Para simular os objetos utilizei fixture objects (fake objects). Porém estou tendo um trabalho considerável para testar a persistência entre as entidades exatamente
por conta de tais relacionamentos e a execução concorrente dos metodos de teste. Problemas do tipo: atributos not-null que devem ser recuperados do banco antes de salvar o objeto que depende dele e objetos que estão sendo salvos em um método já ter sido salvos em métodos executados anteriormente.

**As minhas dúvidas são:**

- Existe um jeito melhor de testar a persistencia tais relacionamentos ?
- É comum testar a camada de persistência desta forma ?
- Posso dizer que este tipo de teste é de integração, visto que estou testando a
  integração entre a camada de serviços e a camada de persistência ?

Comment: Para evitar problemas de concorrência durante os testes de persistência, você pode executar cada teste com uma transação de banco de dados exclusiva e fazer rollback da transação ao final do teste. O bom é que isso exige um design bastante desacoplado, o ruim é que o teu design atual pode não estar tão desacoplado assim (essas heranças acendem uma luz amarela pra mim). Uma dúvida: por que você está testando persistência de dependências? Não confia na estabilidade do Hibernate? Eu uso banco em memória para testar queries que podem ter ficado inválida após refactoring e para testar serviços.

Comment: Quantos aos nomes, eu conheço por "teste de integração" aquilo que testa a integração dos módulos de um sistema, ou a integração entre sistemas. Há quem chame assim os testes da integração do trabalho de diversos desenvolvedores (essa não gosto muito porque isso deveria ser algo natural e super frequente: integrar e testar o trabalho de todos). Os seus testes para mim estão mais pra "testes de serviço", onde você invoca um serviço e deixa essa chamada cruzar todas as camadas do seu sistema (no caso, fachada de serviço -> negócio -> banco de dados).

Comment: O objetivo não é testar o hibernate e sim garantir que os mapeamentos do JPA foram feitos corretamente. Garantir que ao persistir um objeto seus relacionamentos estejam sendo feitos. E que no futuro um outro desenvolvedor não quebre os mapeamentos que foram feito hoje. Obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

Você pode evitar esse trabalho usando o [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/).

Ele permite que você suba uma parte do seu programa para o servidor e execute os testes. Preferencialmente em ambiente idêntico ao da produção.

Da forma que você está fazendo, o teste pode passar e a aplicação falhar quando for colocada em produção, já que o ambiente de testes é diferente.